# Firebase - Is there an API to run clean-up scripts on firebase

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My requirement is to run a clean-up job on my firebase DB.

- Does firebase has an api to run through the database for any such operations?
- If so can we also clean up references of an object within different data sets?

Comment: Please indicate when you cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/UZqYc-ujNWM

Comment: Aside from that, this is incredibly broad. What are you trying to clean up? Can you include an example of your data? When would these jobs runs? Also: you mention both Android and AngularJS. What are you running on?

Comment: I am running a mobile application which is storing the data in firebase.

Comment: Calls are made from angular.
I am not sure if I can explain the data that I have in the firebase :
It is a normal schema 
{
    "data": {
        "data1": {},
        "data2": {},
        "data3": {}
    }
}
Deletion of data2 based on certain condition.

My question was generic only asking for firebaseAPI to do such operations !

Comment: Just to explain the data furthermore : "data2":{"date":ddmmyy, , ,}
want to delete the data expired after a week !
Job will run once a day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, Firebase does not allow you to run scheduled tasks. To do so, you will need to set up a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) which runs a Java or Node.js process to do the cleanup.

The cleanup can be done using the [remove()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/remove.html) method. You might make use of [Firebase queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html) to easily grab the data you need to delete.