# How to automatically delete Firebase inactive users from database and authentication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Even if the users are not anonymous, I would like to automatically delete the user authentication and user info in the database if they have not logged in for say, a year. This is to prevent old or spam accounts from taking up space in Firebase.

Is this possible without manually checking and deleting on the Firebase console?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912899/firebase-is-there-an-api-to-run-clean-up-scripts-on-firebase

Comment: thank you, yes I think cron jobs are the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

This [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node/delete-unused-accounts-cron) do exactly what you need.

[Here more samples for Firebase Cloud Functions.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)